# output a string then do something and add to the same string

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write to the console :

```
Write-Host "Backing up Switch1"
```

Then run the backup and check if it was successful

```
Write-Host "Backing up $Building $SwitchName ..."
$initFldrCount =  Get-ChildItem C:\Admin\$SwitchName | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
C:\kitty_portable-0.70.0.9.exe -ssh -l Admin -pw Password -cmd $Command $ip 
$count++
Start-Sleep 5
$fnlFldrCount = Get-ChildItem C:\Admin\$SwitchName | Measure-Object | ForEach-Object{$_.Count}
#Make sure a backup was made
if (($initFldrCount + 1) -ne $fnlFldrCount){
    $Status = "Failure"
}
else {
    $Status = "Success"
}
Write-Host "===$Status==="
```

it then outputs

```
Backing up Switch-1 ...
===Failure===
```

But I want it to add failure to the end of the Backing up string after the
script

```
Backing up Switch-1 ...  ===Failure===
```

How would I go about doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the -NoNewLine switch to the line

```
Write-Host "Backing up $Building $SwitchName ..."
```

as such:

```
Write-Host "Backing up $Building $SwitchName ..." -NoNewLine
```